# Unable to click the link on IE using IEDriver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The code I am using is shown below.

MultiBrowser

```
package com;    
import java.io.File;    
import org.openqa.selenium.By;    
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;    
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;    
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;    
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;    
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;    
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;   
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;    
import org.testng.annotations.Test;        

public class MultiBrowser {    

  public WebDriver driver;

  // Passing Browser parameter from TestNG xml
  @Parameters("browser")
  @BeforeClass
  public void beforeTest(String browser) {
    // If the browser is Firefox, then do this
   if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {    
     driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   }else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {     
       DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
       capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);    
       File fil = new File("C:\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");            
       System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", fil.getAbsolutePath());    
       driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
   }    
   driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");    
  }

  @Test 
  public void login() throws InterruptedException{    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/a")).click();        
    driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys("testuser_1");        
    driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("Test@123");    
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();    
   }    

  @AfterClass    
  public void afterTest(){    
   driver.quit();    
  }    
}
```

TestNG.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
   <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">    
   <suite name="Suite" parallel="none">    
    <test name="FirefoxTest">    
     <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />    
     <classes>    
      <class name="com.MultiBrowser" />    
     </classes>    
    </test>    
    <test name="IETest">     
     <parameter name="browser" value="ie" />    
     <classes>    
      <class name="com.MultiBrowser" />    
     </classes>     
    </test> 
   </suite>
```

It works fine when I use Firefox but I get the below issue when I run the same code on IE

Exception :

> Unable to find element with xpath == .//*[@id='account']/a (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: how does the rendered HTML look like in IE? Can you please share us the markup

Comment: <a href="http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/your-account/" title="My Account" class="account_icon"><span class="icon">Account</span>My Account<span class="shadow"></span></a>

Comment: You can view the full markup @ http://store.demoqa.com/

Answer (score 0):

It needs to set Security level in all zones. To do that follow the steps below:

1.Open IE

2.Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security

3.All check boxes in Security should be enabled.