# Cannot click element with IEDriverServer

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have an element on a web page that only becomes visible after clicking its parent element. So after clicking a demo in a list of demo's, a row of icons which represent actions for the selected demo is revealed. The following code works fine with both webdriver and chromedriver:

```
demo.click(); //click demo
waitForElementIsDisplayed(demoReservation_btn); //wait until reservation icon is displayed
demoReservation_btn.click(); //click icon
```

Originally i was getting a StaleElementReferenceException and i attempted to fix this by having a try/catch block within a while loop that would continue looping until the icon was clicked. This caused IEDriverServer to crash after a couple of loops.

I have also tried wrapping it up in an Action like so:

```
Action action = new Action(driver);
action.click(demo).click(demoReservation_btn).build().perform()
```

This results in a NoSuchElementException.

I know there are some problems mentioned in the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Hovering_Over_Elements) about browser focus and hovering over elements, but i dont believe this is the problem. I have tried a couple of other things like adding moverToElement to the action, hovering over the element but have had no success with these. I believe one possible solution is to use a javascript executor, but i would like to avoid this approach if possible, any other suggestions?

EDIT

IEDriverServer setup:

```
File file = new File("IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
return driver;
```

Comment: Once refer this:**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660578/unable-to-click-the-link-on-ie-using-iedriver/31002321#31002321**.

Comment: that is part of the required configuration to get IEDriverServer working. I would not have reached the point i am at now without already having done that.

Comment: Use `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);` with ExpectedConditions

Comment: waitForElementIsDisplayed(demoReservation_btn) already waits for the element to be displayed.

Comment: How do you instantiate the IEDriver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling Native events of IE

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
cap.setCapability("nativeEvents",false);
driver  = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
```

I had better result using that in C# version. Read [this](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/01/revisiting-native-events-in-ie-driver.html) to learn why you may need to do this.

Comment: Nice one Saifur, worked first time around, also thanks alot for the explanation link.

Comment: Yes. That's the most concise clarification in terms of `Selenium` and IEDriver given by JimEvans, one of the core contributors of Selenium C# binding

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works for me!