# Protractor - Internet explorer driver doesn't run with selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I've tried any solution on google results about this issue, but nothing is help.

Please help me to figure this out,

thanks!

**Protractor conf:**

```
exports.config = {

  chromeDriver: 'npm/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',
  chromeOnly: false,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  specs: ['c:\\automation\\tests\\testCases\\newApp\\screenshotsTesting.js'],


  multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'firefox',
      'cli': {
      'args': ['webdriver.firefox.useExisting=default']
      // 'args': ['webdriver.firefox.useExisting=default', '-jsconsole', '-jsdebugger']
     }}, 

 {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
     args: ['--test-type','--memory-metrics','--console','--crash-on-failure'] 
    // '--load-extension=' + 'C:\\Users\\idan\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj\\1.2.4_0'
  }
}},

  {
     'browserName': 'internet explorer'
      'platform': 'ANY',
      'version': '11'
    }],


  // maxSessions: 1,

  // rootElement: '.main',

  framework: "jasmine",

  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,

  getPageTimeout: 60000,

....
```

**IE11 tools - all zone level are the same and enabled:**

[image]

**Selenium WD launching:**

```
 java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\automation\npm\node_modules\selenium-standalone\.selenium\iedriver\IEDriverServer.exe -jar C:\automation\npm\node_modules\selenium-standalone\.selenium\selenium-server\2.45.0-server.jar
```

**Protractor launching:**

```
c:\automation\tests\protractor-conf.js --browser="internet explorer" --seleniumAddress=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
```

**Error from Selenium webdriver console:**

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error
 launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all z
ones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled)
for all zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.04 seconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'vCitaQA', ip: '192.168.152.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.ar
ch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.
java:204)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHa
ndler.java:162)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.ja
va:599)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriv
er.java:240)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriv
er.java:225)
        at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDri
ver.java:182)
        at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorer
Driver.java:174)
        at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorer
Driver.java:150)
        ... 14 more
09:19:13.656 WARN - Exception: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Pro
tected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must
be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: The serv
er did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.04 seconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'vCitaQA', ip: '192.168.152.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.ar
ch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
```

Comment: You have to enable all check boxes in security settings. I think you have enabled only Internet option. Location intranet and other options should be enabled.

Comment: refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660578/unable-to-click-the-link-on-ie-using-iedriver/31002321#31002321

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.. but I've already try it and it doesn't help in this case.. :/

Comment: your exception clearly specifying that u didn't enable all check boxes. Or some check boxes are enabled and some are disabled.

Comment: It heard very strange but I'm pretty sure that I've enabled all these 4 check boxes, so it's not the problem although this exception//
any another idea? :/ @SarithaG

Comment: @IdanE try passing `ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true` in the IE config under multiCapabilities