# How to overrride selenium Click() method

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, click

How to override selenium `Click()` method  using C#.
Currently I am using Click method as below -

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("overflow-wrapper")).Click();
```

Upon calling Click method in the script, Selenium should invoke Click method overridden by me.

Thanks.
Amol.

Comment: Why do you want to override click() method. if you perform any click in that method, you have to make each and every element as global where you want to perform clicking on.

Comment: Actually .Click() method is not working while executing script on IE11. So I want to implement below work around in overridden method   ILocatable clickItem = (ILocatable)item;
IMouse mouse = ((IHasInputDevices)driver).Mouse;
mouse.Click(clickItem.Coordinates);

Comment: click() method will work in all browser, if that is not working that may be the problem with your browser. I post IE browser related answer, Once check that.

Comment: check this answer, it may be helpful for you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446771/protractor-internet-explorer-driver-doesnt-run-with-selenium-webdriver/31449284#31449284

Comment: @Saritha G - Other code and Selenium commands works fine on IE. Even Click() method work fine on Firefox. There is problem with only Click method on IE.

Comment: which one is on IE can you post IE working code..??

Answer (score 1):

You can not override this method unless it is marked as virtual (and it's not).

If you want to have you own clicking method you can simply created it.

If you want to have it in your IWebElement class then you can add it to the class the next way:

```
 public static IWebElement Click(this IWebElement element)
        {
            //here is your implementation 
            return element;
        }
```

This method must be in static class. So in this way you just extant existing class adding one more method.

Comment: I have more than 400 scripts in my test suite. Click method is working fine for Mozilla Firefox browser. But while executing these scripts on IE; Click method is not working. So I have work around as - ILocatable clickItem = (ILocatable)item; IMouse mouse = ((IHasInputDevices)driver).Mouse; mouse.Click(clickItem.Coordinates); . Now I want to override click method with this work around code(Which works on both firefox and IE) so that there will be minimum changes in my framework

Comment: It seems that using extension you can use the same name of the method so it will override it.

Comment: How to write that overridden method.

Comment: I've changed my answer, please look

Comment: @Denis-Thank you for your help. But Selenium's click method is not accepting any argument - driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("overflow-wrapper")).Click();........I want to override this method not overload

Comment: Just copy paste my code to static class... Don't be lazy!