# Selenium NoSuchElementException with InternetExplorerDriver

Tags: selenium

I'm doing some R&D with Selenium and I've found an inconsistancy I can't explain between the InternetExplorerDriver and the ChromeDriver.

I run this code:

```
        var driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        var query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        query.SendKeys("Hello World!");
        query.Submit();
```

Everything works fine, my browser navigates to google and searches for "Hello World!".

But when I try exactly the same code with the InternetExplorerDriver

```
        var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        var query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        query.SendKeys("Hello World!");
        query.Submit();
```

I get an error on the FindElement line.

> An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException' occurred
>   in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to find element on closed window

I have IE 11.0.9600.17905 installed.

Am I missing a step with IE?

Comment: I think you didn't enable all checkboxes in IE. Once check this  ** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660578/unable-to-click-the-link-on-ie-using-iedriver/31002321#31002321 **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [required configuration](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration) section on the IEDriver wiki. I would hazard a guess and say your problem is "you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value".